# Excel - VLOOKUP with 2 conditions?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2013

Wondering if anyone can help.
I have 2 tables. The first one has a list of which dates each vendor work against their team leader name. Displaying only:
dates they worked (A) .... vendor name (B) .... the team leader (C)
This table has got 400 lines.

The second table has a list of ALL donations each vendor did per day. Some vendors has got 5 or 6 items per day. This table is pretty similar with the first one, but because the team leader change from one day to another, one vendor may get 2 or 3 different leaders every week (but only one on a day).
This table has got 10.000 lines.

So the columns of this table are:
dates they worked (G) .... vendor name (J) .... the team leader (K)

But the K column is not populated. I need a formula that goes something like on the K column: 
if (G)=(A)  AND  (J)=(B) return the value (C) into (K)

Can anyone help with this?

Cheer,
Bruno

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use an array version of INDEX:MATCH formula:

```
=INDEX(A:C,MATCH(G1&J1,A:A&B:B,0),3)
```

NOTE: this formula must be entered with `ctrl+shift+enter`
[image]

Comment: Perfect... Thanks for that Jacob